# MySQL subquery syntax error for cumulative totals

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
test_id | id | option | visits
------------------------------
1       | 1  | a      | 7
1       | 2  | b      | 12
1       | 3  | a      | 2
1       | 4  | b      | 4
```

I need to get the cummulative totals of visits for option 'a' and option 'b'.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT *,
    ( SUM(visits) WHERE `option` = 'a' ) as visitsA, 
    ( SUM(visits) WHERE `option` = 'b' ) as visitsB
    FROM `table`
    WHERE test_id = 1
```

I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `option` = 'a' ) as visitsA, ( SUM(visits) WHERE `option` = 'b' ' at line 2
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level - e.g., with a bit of PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Such "WHERE" isn't allowed in `SUM()`. Instead, do:

```
SELECT *,
    SUM(IF(`option`='a', visits, 0)) as visitsA, 
    SUM(IF(`option`='b', visits, 0)) as visitsB
FROM `table`
WHERE test_id = 1
```